# Line 18:19: 'value' is missing in props validation

Tags: reactjs

I have this register page and it keeps showing me this error "Line 18:19:'value' is missing in props validation":

```
const Register = () =>{

const [value, setMyValue] = useState()
```

This function shows up a component based on the choice of the user that happens in the select tag

```
const Choice = ({ value }) =>{

if (value === "true"){
return <Employee />
}else{
return <Employer />
}
}

return(
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container-xxl bg-primary page-header">
<div className="container text-center">
<h1 className="text-white animated zoomIn">Sign Up</h1>
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
 
</nav>
</div>
</div>

<div className="container-xxl py-5" id="contact">
<div className="container">
<div className="mx-auto text-center wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s" style= 
{{maxWidth: 600}}>
  
  <div className="d-inline-block border rounded-pill text-primary px-4 mb-2">Sign Up 
  As</div>
  <select onChange={(e)=>{setMyValue(e.target.value)}} className="form-select" aria- 
  label="Default select example">

  <option value="false">Employer</option>
  <option value="true">Employee</option>
  </select>
  <h2 className="mb-5 mt-4">Sign Up to find the best employees</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
  <Choice value={ value } />
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
    
  )
  }
```

And this is the line 18 by the way:

```
const Choice = ({ value }) =>{
```

Comment: did you pass the `value` prop in `Choice` component from `Register` component?

Comment: yes go down in the code you will see it, isn't like this <Choice value={value} />?

Comment: yes i saw that but that was inside `Choice`

Comment: could you share the full code of `Register`?

Comment: Is this from ESLint react/prop-types? Do you have your propTypes defined?

Comment: @miraj stackoverfllow doesn't allow me to put the whole code

Comment: no idea smashed-potatoes how do i know if its defined or not

Comment: See: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: `const Register = () =>{
const [value, setMyValue] = useState()
return (
    <Choice value-{value} />
  )
}`

Comment: what really makes me mad that page was working perfectly and then i cahnged something so i got that error, i pressed ctrl+z until i went back to where i was and the error didn't go away

Comment: i did get you @miraj inside the return i already have that piece of code

Comment: smashed-potatoes that didn't help me i didn't quiet understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem could be 2 brackets in line 7?

```
if (value === "true"){
return <Employee />
}else{
return <Employer />
}
```

Comment: which one is the line 7 for you

Comment: const Choice = ({ value }) =>{ this is the first line

Comment: nope thats not the issue bro

Comment: By the way, is it possible to have <Choice /> component inside its self function?

Comment: Don't worry guys i restarted my pc and now it works and the most important part take a break if you are tilted!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).